# ipython notebook requires javascript - on firefox web browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run jupyter notebook from a terminal on Xfce Ubuntu machine. 
I typed in the command:

jupyter notebook --browser=firefox

The firefox browser opens, but it is empty and with the following error:

"IPython Notebook requires JavaScript. Please enable it to proceed."

I searched the web on how to enable JavaScript on Ipython NoteBook but didn't find an answer. I would appreciate a lot any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

javascript has to be enabled in firefox browser it is turned off. to turn it on do this

> To enable JavaScript for Mozilla Firefox: Click the Tools drop-down menu and select Options. Check the boxes next to Block pop-up windows, Load images automatically, and Enable JavaScript. Refresh your browser by right-clicking anywhere on the page and selecting Reload, or by using the Reload button in the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem really was that JavaScript was disabled on Firefox. However, the steps you wrote are not applicable on the current version of Firefox browser. I will write how I managed to enable JavaScript on Firefox in a separate box.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the address bar, type "about:config" (with no quotes), and press Enter.
   Click "I'll be careful, I promise".
2. In the search bar, search for "javascript.enabled" (with no quotes).
   Right click the result named "javascript.enabled" and click "Toggle". JavaScript is now enabled.
3. To Re-disable JavaScript, repeat these steps.